# Cannot get 'admin-delete-user-account' test to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have created a function where an admin can delete a user account on their dashboard. This function works successfully in practice.

(I have deleted user accounts through the admin dashboard and have confirmed with rails console.)

However, I cannot get an rspec test to pass testing this function. It always returns that the user account is still present.

The form on the site:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: admin_user_path(@user), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, html: { method: :delete } do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Delete account", class:"danger", data: { test: "delete-user-account" } %>
<% end %>
```

Test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature 'deleting users' do
  let!(:admin) { create :admin }

  scenario 'successfully deleted an external user account' do
    sign_in admin, scope: :admin

    user = create(:user)
    visit admin_user_path(user)

    find('[data-test="delete-user-account"]').click

    visit root_path
    expect(user).not_to be_present
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to accept the alert "Are you sure?"

If you use the Selenium API you can do:

```
find('[data-test="delete-user-account"]').click

page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept

visit root_path
expect(user).not_to be_present
```

Comment: Thanks! We do have the `selenium-webdriver` gem as our driver, but it returns `undefined method 'switch_to' for #<Capybara::RackTest::Browser:####>`

Comment: This is the whole error: ```1) deleting users successfully deleted an external user account
     Failure/Error: page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `switch_to' for #<Capybara::RackTest::Browser:0x00007fbc4a501050>
     # ./spec/features/internal/user_management/deleting_users_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

Comment: We're using using `chromedriver` which requires `selenium/webdriver`